# How does the accumulator value in reduce method change without explicitly changing it?

Tags: javascript, reduce

This is my first time writing here, so apologies in advance.

I am pretty sure I have a good grasp on the reduce() method, but I can't seem to wrap my head around one concept in particular. In this particular problem, we are asked to find elements that all of the array arguments share. I was able to construct an answer with the reduce method. I know that it works, and I know there are more efficient solutions, but I can't seem to understand how the accumulator value revises itself even though I have not reassigned its value.

Let me explain: after the first iteration of the current values which is the second array, I check to see if the current elements share commonalities with my accumulator(the first array). After checking and pushing the common values into results, `results = [5, 15, 7]`. The accumulator value at the beginning of the next iteration also becomes my set of results values, but again, I do not explicitly reassign the accumulator value, for example with `acc = results` . How does accumulator "understand" to change without explicit changes? I've kinda just accepted this mechanism as is, but would love an explanation. Please let me know if I should offer more clarification. Thank you!

```
function intersection(arrays) {
    return arrays.reduce((acc, curr) => {
// here, acc = the first array --> 5, 15, 7 --> 15, 5
    
    let results = []

    for(let element of curr) {
      if(acc.includes(element)) results.push(element)
    }

// here, results = 5, 15, 7 --> 15, 5 --> 15, 5
    
    return results
  })
}

const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 7, 3];
const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7, 21];
const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20, 21];

console.log(intersection([arr1, arr2, arr3])); 
// should log: [5, 15]
```

Comment: It would have been easier if you would've used `set`.

Comment: when you return something from `reduce` then it will become `acc` value in next iteration

Comment: It is logging `[15, 5]`, So what are your expecting other than this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @charlietfl, I have read the docs and interpreted this specific definition as pertaining to situations in which you return acc. However, it makes sense that it applies to any return value:

"Your reducer function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array, and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value."

Comment: @decpk I'm not expecting another return value and I understand that there are simpler solutions. I mostly understand reduce, but I'm specifically asking how acc is reassigned without specific reassignment. However, as per your 2nd comment, I understand now that an inherent functionality of reduce is that even if you don't specifically return acc or reassign it, acc becomes the value you return from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably understand it better seeing this rudimentary version of reduce that simply sums the array values when called

```js
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, start) {
  // inital value of acc is start value `0` set in call
  let acc = start; 

  this.forEach((elem, i) => {
    // acc gets assigned the return value from the callback 
    // every iteration of this internal loop
    acc = callback(acc, elem, i, this)
  });
  // then finally gets returned from the outer function
  return acc
};

const arr = [1, 2, 3]

const res = arr.myReduce((a, c, i, arr) => {
  return a + c // returned to `acc` in the forEach loop above
}, 0)

console.log('Result:', res) // expect 1+2+3 = 6
```

Comment: I mostly understand how reduce works and this function in particular explicitly reassigns acc and returns it. However, the example I showed above does not explicitly return acc nor reassigns it, but acc still takes the values from results after each iteration. I'm learning that this is just an inherent feature of reduce.

Comment: You are missing the whole point. Anything you return becomes `acc` in next iteration or final result when it is last iteration. My example is  how reduce works under the hood. In your example you return `results` which becomes next `acc`. Nothing says you need to return the same `acc` . What you return depends on the use case

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks for the clarification Charlie!